Correction for multiple comparison across models with related dependent variables
To clarify this is a repost, I made adjustments so that it is more concise and clear.
I am statistically evaluating my experiment by using linear mixed effects models. The experiment is comprised of several different intervention protocols done within subject at a random sequence. During each intervention there are 3 different time periods. I wish to evaluate the effect of the intervention protocol within each of these time periods and the differences between time periods within each intervention protocol.
Specifically my model is as follows:
fit_simple <- lmer(log(target_variable) ~ Protocol * period + sex + 
               (1 | participant), data = input_data, REML = TRUE)

(the data is log transformed so the assumption of normality of residuals is met - please don't comment on this it is not relevant to the question).
I am running this model 4 times on slightly different data that is correlated and in biological sense related (4 different HRV parameters calculated from the same beat-to-beat ECG data). To answer my question on whether there are differences between time periods within each protocol and whether there are differences between protocols within each time period I am running pairwise comparison using estimated marginal means (emmeans package R).
emm <- emmeans(fit_simple, ~ Protocol * period)

# Pairwise comparisons between levels of period within each Protocol

pairwise_comparisons_Protocol <- contrast(emm, method = "pairwise", 
                                  by = "Protocol", adjust = "tukey")

# Pairwise comparisons between levels of Protocol within each period

pairwise_comparisons_period <- contrast(emm, method = "pairwise", 
                                 by = "period", adjust = "tukey")

To correct for family-wise error rate I am using Tukey's HSD.
Afterwards I also do corrections across all families of pairwise comparisons within the model using Holm:
all_pvals <- data.frame(
  comparison = c(rep("Protocol_within_Period", 
  length(summary_protokol$p.value)),
                 rep("Period_within_Protocol", 
  length(summary_obdobje$p.value))),
  p_value = c(summary_protokol$p.value, summary_obdobje$p.value)
)
all_pvals$holm_adjusted <- p.adjust(all_pvals$p_value, 
                                    method = "holm")

So what I am left with is to account for 4 correlated and related dependent variables. I would need to correct across all families of pairwise comparisons of all 4 models which would correct for type 1 error for sure, but also probably increase the likelihood of type 2 error too much.
Is there a better way of doing this kind of correction that is less conservative? This is my first time doing several linear models on variables that are correlated so I am a bit lost. Should I redo modeling and incorporate all 4 variables into a multivariate model?

The word "correction" seems to imply that there is one "correct" way of doing this, but in fact it is a trade-off. As far as I can see, what you do or have in mind to do is very safe and very conservative, i.e., you control the overall type I error, but indeed this will come with a high probability of type II error. If you "correct" less (for example, you don't take a final "control" step), type I error is controlled for individual tests but not overall, and you are less conservative. Whether this is fine depends on the requirements of your field really, and isn't a matter of right or wrong.

PS I didn't make this an answer because it's a general consideration and it is well possible that specific things can be done in the given situation that are more convincing than just not running some corrections. But generally, it'll always be a trade-off.

You will see these applications (handling all sources of correlation correctly, including multivariate) discussed with computer implementations in the books "Resampling Based Multiple Testing....", "Multiple Comparisons and Multiple Tests Using SAS," and "Multiple Comparisons Using R".

There are many schools of thought on all this. Personally, I would treat each model as its own universe and not try to adjust between them. I think many people are comfortable with adjusting each family separately -- a family being comparisons within each level of any "by" variable.

It is common in the pharmaceutical industry to consider multiple endpoints, which is an example of multivariate dependent variables, as a single family of comparisons. Regulatory agencies might be concerned that when you treat them separately it is too easy to "win."
